# Adding picture to Excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I'm trying to add a picture to my excel sheet. This is my code:

```
string AppDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
Range oRange = (Range)ar.Cells[2, 1];
float Left = (float)((double)oRange.Left);
float Top = (float)((double)oRange.Top);
const float ImageSize = 32;
ar.Shapes.AddPicture(AppDirectory + "ReportIcon" + "\\Bedab-Logo-Blue", Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, Left, Top, (float)1.41, (float)0.4);
                        oRange.RowHeight = ImageSize + 2;
```

But this line of code,

```
ar.Shapes.AddPicture(AppDirectory + "ReportIcon" + "\\Bedab-Logo-Blue", Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, Left, Top, (float)1.41, (float)0.4);
```

throws the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The specified file wasn't found.

Note: the path is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing file extension try adding Bedab-Logo-Blue extension like .jpg .png etc

```
ar.Shapes.AddPicture(AppDirectory + "ReportIcon" + "\\Bedab-Logo-Blue.JPG",
Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, 
Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, Left, Top, (float)1.41, (float)0.4);
```

I added .JPG, you have to add as per your desired file type